# Local variable not updated in loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, initialization

I created an Object Array und then initialized the Array within a loop.
But when I call a method with the Object Array, it tells me, the variable has not been initialized. What did I do wrong and how can I get it right?

```
Objects[] = object;
for (int i = 0; i < someMap.size(); i++) {
    object = new Object[someMap.size()];      
    for (Entry e : someMap.entrySet) {
        object[i] = new Object(var1, var2, var3);
    }   
}
somemethod(somevar, object); //Eclipse tells me: The local variable object may not have been initialized
```

Comment: Your posted code is useless for figuring out your problem. Surely you'd show us the variable that the compiler is complaining about, right?

Comment: it won't even compile due to first and third lines. You use Objects and Object classes. Object probably overrides java.lang.Object according to constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make this changes:

```
Objects[] object = null;
```

This is because, you are initializing your array inside for loop but the compiler doesn't know that at compile time, so it generates compile time error saying `The local variable may not have been initialized`

Also you might not have initialzed `somevar` variable before passing it to `somemethod`